# JQuery Js Script only work in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below code works fine on google chrome only. Other browsers return *Only mp3 file type allowed.* Help fix please

```
$("#song").change(function () {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var songfile = file.type;
    var match = ["audio/mp3"];
    var addResult = "#music_formresult";
    $(addResult).empty(); //remove previous error message
    if (!((songfile == match))) {
        $(addResult).html("**Only mp3 file type allowed.**");
        $("#songName").html("Select Song");
        return false;
    } else {
        var filename = $('#song').val().split('\\').pop();
        $("#songName").html(filename);
    }
});
```

Comment: use `.on('change', function() {` - I've had issues with calling the shorthand selectors across browsers

Comment: That makes no sense @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs. `change` just does exactly what you've described under the hood.

Comment: @Liam I know -- but trust me, I've had compatibility issues - not sure why but I have - though that being said this was a fairly old jquery version - could have improved in recent versions

Comment: I have tried .on('change, function(){... It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a string to an array, which is weird but probably will work fine on all browsers.

You have extra parenthesis on the if statement but that isn't the cause either, however I would remove them anyways.

My guess is the following is not being consistent across all browsers

```
var file = this.files[0];
var songfile = file.type;
```

In order for me to be able to help you, please provide a codepen sample of your code running, or place a breakpoint inside the function and show me the value for the above lines on a browser that is not Chrome.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer to the question.